# Issue with smartindent in Vim

Tags: vim, auto-indent

In vim with smartindent on:

1. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after say an if-statement
2. Type in <kbd>{</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice
4. Type in <kbd>}</kbd>
5. If you hit <kbd>↑</kbd> and go to the previous line, indentation is removed from the blank line.

Even the vim documentation says that:

*If you do not type anything on the new line except `<BS>` or `CTRL-D` and then type `<Esc>`, `CTRL-O` or `<CR>`, the indent is deleted again.*

Is there any way to keep this indentation and not have it deleted?

Comment: sadly i'm not on a computer with vim so i can't try this, but have you tried just hitting enter once, putting in the brace, escaping to go to command mode then using uppercase O to insert a line above to see if that indents?

Comment: @Victor, thanks for the suggestion. I think I've found a middle ground with this, I just have to train myself to press enter once, type } and then press up and then enter. Won't work in all situations though.

Answer (score 8):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to start editing on a blank line (from command mode, obviously).  This will start your cursor off with the expected level of indentation.

---

Another doesn't-answer-the-question-as-asked-but-is-a-better-solution-overall:

When typing an opening brace in insert mode, this will insert a matching set of braces
and leave the cursor on a new line in the middle.

```
:imap { {<CR>}<Esc>O
```

Similarly, this will auto-insert matching parens and square brackets.

```
:imap ( ()<Left>
:imap [ []<Left>
```

(Strip off the leading `:` when adding to `vimrc`.)

As I commented on Victor's answer, changing Vim's indentation behavior will leave "empty" lines containing extraneous spaces throughout your files.  IMO, this is completely intolerable.

Comment: I'm voting this up, in part, because I'd never heard of the <kbd> tag before.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question, precisely, but it's super-useful! How did I now know about this?

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me, I sometimes use `ddko` (or `ddO`) to delete the line without enough spaces and open a new line with the correct indent. Or, I'll just press `A` and then `Tab` enough times to get to the correct indent.

Answer (score 1):

the article [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Prevent_autoindent_from_removing_indentation) talks about you're very same problem, and what to put in vimrc to fix it.

```
inoremap <CR> <CR><Space><BS>
nnoremap o o<Space><BS>
nnoremap O O<Space><BS>
```

I havn't exactly tested this tho.

also the same article links to a shorter [alternate solution](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1019).

Comment: This will litter the file with "blank" lines containing nothing but spaces, which is rather ugly, especially with :set list.  I'd prefer not to change Vim's normal indentation behavior.

Comment: Thanks - op here, I guess I'll have to live with this solution. Not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is `{<CR>}<esc>shift+o` as it outpaces `{<CR><CR>}<esc>k shift+s` by several strokes. I get in a rut with it, though, and end up just using o or O to grab new, properly-indented lines off an empty when I should be using S.

That is, set up your bracing structure and open line-above:

```
if (true) {
}//cursor here, press shift-o
```

And you get the indenting you expect.

The open-above trick isn't any fewer keypresses than `<up><end><cr>`, but with escape remapped and shift being chorded, you can throw it in quite fast.

Also, don't forget your manual indent reset and block-movement. If you're inside a mangled curly brace block, simply use `={` (or `=i{` if you're on top of one of the braces). I use that when I have a Good Idea that needs to see text asap, and I don't worry about any formatting frippery until I take a breather.